# MirrorAPI - is there a way to detect if URL payload in OPEN_URI action is down or not successfully sent

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is there a way to detect if URL payload in OPEN_URI action is down or not successfully sent.

Especially if this it's a custom url protocol.

---

Example:

url payload: customprotocol://open

where customprotocol is defined in the manifest as in

Android native app, add in mainfest intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="customprotocol" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then launching native apk as mirror api action payload:

```
{
      "id": "launchMe",
      "action": "OPEN_URI",
      "values": [
        {
          "displayName": "Open",
        }
      ],
      "payload": "customprotocol://open"
}
```

**If customprotocol isn't launched, ie., if apk is not installed, is there a way to detect that?**

(Technique from: ) 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/106035004831103549307/posts/E1XqxCoNBD7

Comment: Could you give us an example URL that you're sending? Do you want Glass to show an error message if no Activity could handle the protocol you used?

Comment: added example above under the line

Comment: This sounds like a bug. The menu item should not appear if no activity  can handle the protocol. If you're seeing other behavior, can you file a bug report in the issue tracker? http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list